# A number of successful Android in-app purchases don't show up in the Play Console

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-play-console

One of my Android apps has a number of in-app products. I've set up some analytics so that whenever there's a new purchase I get an email.
However in a significant number of cases (it varies but sometimes it's like 1-5%) these seemingly successful and valid purchases don't get registered in the Play Console.
And as far as I can tell it's not a bug in my code that's registering failed purchases.

I've set up some additional analytics to try to figure out what are these (is it hacking or something else) and some interesting things show up:

1. The "proper" Google Play orders have an ID in the form "GPA. ...-...-...-...". These orders however all have IDs in the form "NumbersNumbersNumbers"
2. The in-app products cost $1.49, so what users see is "$1.49", "1.49 EUR", etc.
   For these purchases however the users that made them see something like "0.2" - so no currency and also the product doesn't cost 0.2 in any country
3. For the "proper" orders the originalJSON field contains "acknowledge:false" var. These orders don't have this "acknowledged" field
4. these orders usually come in burst - all 6 products purchased within 20 seconds, which is something that no regular user ever does

So to me these look like some internal Google test orders however I haven't found any information on the topic that says Google is making such orders.

I'm curious if anybody knows anything about these and if it is a common thing.

Thanks!